# A Foreach in a div is only retrieving the last value

Tags: php

I have been searching for the solution for so long with no success.

I set a div with a foreach that displays pictures with their respective caption, which works perfectly, and I also set a delete option but when I click on the image I want to delete, it only retrieves the last value in the div (let's say I have 10 images and I want to delete the image number 3, it gives me the value of the image number 10).

Here is my code that works fine to display the images:

```
$a1 = new ArrayIterator($newrow);
$a2 = new ArrayIterator($newrowcaption);

$it = new MultipleIterator;
$it->attachIterator($a1);
$it->attachIterator($a2);

foreach($it as $e =>$ekey) {
  ?><form action ='' method='POST'>
  <?php

  echo '<div class="boxpic">'."<img src='../../pictures/pics/{$ekey[0]}' height='120' width='auto' />"."<br />". $ekey[1]."<input type='submit' class='deleteinput' name='deletepic' . ' value='Delete' >"."<br />".'</div>';
}
```

And here is my attempt to retrieve the value from a specific image

```
if(isset($_POST['deletepic'])){
  foreach ($ekey as $ekey1=>$newvalue) {
    var_dump($newvalue);
  }
}
```

I can't find the solution to get the current value of the image I want to delete. (Note: I am using var_dump since I wanted to see the output) Can you please give me some hints?

Comment: Move the `<form>` element outside of the `foreach` loop

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach($it as $e =>$ekey) :
  ?>
    <form action ='' method='POST'>
      <div class="boxpic">
        <img src='../../pictures/pics/<?php echo $ekey[0]; ?>' height='120' width='auto' />
        <br />
        <?php echo $ekey[1]; ?>

// i'm making a guess as to the pic id...is it in ekey[3]?  anyway
// put the pic id here in the hidden input var for this form
// change $ekey[3] in this next line to the element of the unqiue id

        <input type='hidden' name='deletepic' value='<?php echo $ekey[3]; ?>'>
        <input type='submit' class='deleteinput' name='deletepic' value='Delete'>
        <br />
      </div>
    </form>
  ?>
endforeach;
```

Comment: I moved the <form> outside but the result is still the same. The problem seems to be with this

     if(isset($_POST['deletepic'])){
    foreach ($ekey as $ekey1=>$newvalue) {
            var_dump($newvalue);
    }
    }

Also, can I give a specific id for each of images? maybe this is the solution?

Comment: i think you commented on the wrong solution.  i have not suggested moving the form outside.  in fact, i think you need it inside the loop...one form for each.  what i don't know is what `$ekey` element contains the unqiue id for that pic.

Comment: Yes, sorry for commenting on the wrong solution. Maybe the result of the var_dump when I click on the submit button can help?

string 'pic10.jpg' (length=9)

string 'Caption 10' (length=10)

And it doesn't matter which image you want to delete. It always returns me the same result.

Comment: does each picture have a unique id in the data?  if so, what element is that in the `$ekey` element in the iterator?

Comment: Yes, each picture have a unique id in the data: my database has 10 columns named respectively pic1, pic2, pic3,... and 10 columns named respectively caption1, caption2, caption3,... None of the picture saved in the database have the same name. The iterator was to combine both pic and their respective caption in the same div.

Comment: try my code snippet and change `$ekey[3]` so that it is the unique id for the image.  then you will have within `$_POST['deletepic']` the id that you wish to delete.

Comment: I tried your code and it still shows the same. You're right, I think the issue is that I don't have a unique id for the image. How can I add an id for the image in the for each loop?

Comment: it's not clear what you are trying to do.  but as for your code snippet, once you determine how you are referencing things, my example should work for you with a minor change to the unique identifier.

Comment: You actually have no idea how much you helped me by telling me about the unique id for the image! Thank you so much! The only thing I had to change from your code is to have a different name for each input. I can now delete the image I want. Thank you again!

Comment: great! if this is the correct solution, please mark it as such for other people that may have this problem.

Comment: Done with pleasure! Thank you for your time in helping me!